# MySQL connection gets closed in between the operation in Hibernate application

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

My Applications installed on Apache tomcat was running successfully,then we installed new Apache for installing Bugzilla , Bugzilla was installed successfully and is working, My Apache Tomcat is running on port 1891 and Apache for Bugzilla is running on port 80, when both runs simultaneously my applications installed on tomcat stops working.

My Application performs two operation 
1.Insertion 
2. Some other Heavy Operation based on point 1

when a request comes for Insertion , my application behaves well and does insertion,but fails to perform the 2 operation and gives following exception:

```
    Hibernate: select vendor0_.vendor_coupon_id as vendor1_, vendor0_.name as name1_, vendor0_.heading as heading1_, vendor0_.artwork1 as artwork4_1_, vendor0_.artwork2 as artwork5_1_, vendor0_.redeem_doc as redeem6_1_, vendor0_.icon as icon1_, vendor0_.pkg_name as pkg8_1_, vendor0_.apk as apk1_, vendor0_.country as country1_, vendor0_.description as descrip11_1_ from vendor vendor0_ where vendor0_.country=?
org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute query
    at org.hibernate.exception.ErrorCodeConverter.handledNonSpecificException(ErrorCodeConverter.java:92)
    at org.hibernate.exception.ErrorCodeConverter.convert(ErrorCodeConverter.java:80)
    at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:43)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:1565)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:1545)
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:375)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:271)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:840)
    at org.hibernate.impl.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:74)
    at com.learning.controller.VendorCRUD.getVendorsForCountry(VendorCRUD.java:137)
    at com.avilyne.rest.resource.CouponBinding.UpdateCoupon(CouponBinding.java:50)
    at com.avilyne.rest.resource.CouponBinding.run(CouponBinding.java:44)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: No operations allowed after connection closed.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1014)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:988)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:974)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:919)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.throwConnectionClosedException(ConnectionImpl.java:1269)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.checkClosed(ConnectionImpl.java:1261)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.prepareStatement(ConnectionImpl.java:4246)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.prepareStatement(ConnectionImpl.java:4212)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor65.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GooGooStatementCache$1StmtAcquireTask.run(GooGooStatementCache.java:525)
    at com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:547)
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: The last packet successfully received from the server was 75,824,749 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 75,824,749 milliseconds ago. is longer than the server configured value of 'wait_timeout'. You should consider either expiring and/or testing connection validity before use in your application, increasing the server configured values for client timeouts, or using the Connector/J connection property 'autoReconnect=true' to avoid this problem.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1117)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.send(MysqlIO.java:3829)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2449)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2629)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2719)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2155)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:2318)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(NewProxyPreparedStatement.java:76)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.getResultSet(AbstractBatcher.java:118)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:1239)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:374)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:210)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:1562)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:1545)
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:375)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:271)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:840)
    at org.hibernate.impl.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:74)
    at com.learning.controller.VendorCRUD.getVendorById(VendorCRUD.java:153)
    at com.avilyne.rest.resource.VendorOffers.getOffers(VendorOffers.java:69)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor84.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$ResponseOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:205)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:288)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1483)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1414)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1363)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1353)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:414)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:537)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:708)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:947)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1009)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:109)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:153)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:140)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.send(MysqlIO.java:3810)
    ... 53 more
```

following is my Hibernate configuration file:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD     `3//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">` 
<hibernate-configuration> 
<session-factory> 
<property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property> 
<property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/offers?autoReconnect=true</property> 
<property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property> 
<property name="show_sql">true</property> 
<property name="connection.password">password</property> 
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">5</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">20</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">300</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">3000</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">50</property>
<property name="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">20</property>
<property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">false</property>
<property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property> 
<property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
<property name="dynamic-update">true</property>
<mapping resource="person.hbm.xml"/>
<mapping resource="vendor.hbm.xml"/>
<mapping resource="coupons.hbm.xml"/>
<mapping resource="binding.hbm.xml"/>
<mapping resource="mperson.hbm.xml"/>
</session-factory> 
</hibernate-configuration>
```

when we stop Apache on which bugzilla is installed , My applications installed on tomcat runs well.

looking at the log it seems to me that after insert operation database connection gets closed and hence second operation is not performed. I am not able to figure out how the connection gets closed?
I forgot to add both server (Apache with bugzilla installed and Tomcat with my applications installed) use the same mysql server and every this is running on ubuntu machine with 4 Gb ram and i5.

Comment: I would guess that there aren't enough connections to satisfy the tomcat and bugzilla applications needs.

Comment: If its matter on enough connections then why my application suffers, and as far as I know cp03 will auto increment number of connections by 3 if connections are less

Comment: My guess is that there aren't enough connections available on the MySQL server itself. Your pool may ask for as many connections as it wants, but if MySQL has been configured to only allow 5, you won't be able to have more than 5.